# RSelenium - Storing data in an array

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I'm extracting events description from a list of event in my website.
Each event is a href link which goes to another page where we can find the image and the description of the event. I'm trying to store the image url and the description of all events in an array so I used the code below in the end of my loop, but I only get the image and the description of the last event looped:

```
      m<-c(images_of_events)
      n<-c( description_of_events)

 cc<-remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[class = '_24er']")
 cc<-remDr$getPageSource()
 page_events<-read_html(cc[[1]][1])
 links_events_data=html_nodes(page_events,'._24er > table > tbody > tr > td > 
 div> div._4dmk > a ')

events_urls<-html_attr(links_events_data,"href")
```

//the loop of each event

```
for (i in events_urls) {
  remDr$navigate(paste("localhost://www.mywebsite",i,sep="")) 
  #get image
  imagewebElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "scaledImageFitWidth")
  images_of_events<-imagewebElem $getElementAttribute("src")
  descriptionwebElem <-remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[class = '_63ew']")
  descriptionwebElem <-remDr$getPageSource()

  page_event_description<-read_html(descriptionwebElem[[1]][1])
  events_desc =html_nodes(page_event_description,'._63ew > span')

  description_of_events= html_text(events_desc)
  m<-c(images_of_events)
  n<-c( description_of_events)

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save values in array in R you have to

1) create the array/data.frame `dta <- data.frame(m=c(),n=c())` and then save to it `dta[i,1] <- image_of_events` and `dta[i,2] <- description_of_evants` where `i` is numeric iterator

2) create the array/data.frame and use `rbind` to add values like `dta <- rbind(dta, data.frame(m=images_of_events, n = description_of_events))`

Comment: I added in the globbal for loop :   for (i in events_urls) {
    m[i]<-images_of_events
    n[i]<-events_desc
  }

Comment: `i` should be numeric so `i in 1:length(events_urls)` or `i = 1` before loop and `i=i+1` inside and loop can be anything `for(urls in events_urls)`